# nsnotificationcenter method fired more than once

Tags: iphone, nsnotification

i have a viewcontroller .In it there is a nsnotification observer in it. i am posting the notification from another viewcontroller.but the nsnotification observers selector get fired two or sometimes three times. My question is that when i use [view removeFromSuperview];
to remove this viewcontrollers view ,is the notification observer removed? I have given this method at the dealloc method of the viewcontroller class

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

that method will be called when the viewcontrollers retain count becomes 0

You should add another method that will be called when the view is removed from the other viewcontroller and call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

For the issue that the selector is called multiple times, I would need to see more code - make sure that the line of code thats posting the notification isnt being called multiple times

Comment: no the postnotification method is called only once.  now it can be two  ways ...either two instances of the viewcontroller is there. or that notification observer which was not removed earlier is firing...

Comment: true - try logging self and see if the same addresses are printed

Comment: ya that was the reason logging self gave different addresses for the same class name

Answer (score 1):

`NSNotification` registered to whole app (or even for all operating system), not to single view or viewcontroller.  You have need for remove observer in your action if it won't longer used. In this case you can handle only one posted notification.